# "Calumny attempt" Is it a legit English phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, cultural-phrases

Lets say someone attempting to calumny, by fabricating a a written document. 
Can I call this event as "Calumny attempt"?

Comment: Its adjective is "calumnious", if that's any help.  But perhaps "an attempt at calumny" is what you want to say.

Comment: "calumnious" feels pretty obscure to me. It may not be understood (depending on the audience).

Comment: @WS2: Do you call *a suicide attempt* a *suicidal attempt*? An *evasion attempt* an *evasive attempt*? You need to use a noun here, although I agree that *attempt at calumny* is indeed more idiomatic.

Comment: @JamesRandom Obscure? *Calumnious* is used tenfold more often than **the *other* adjective** associated with *calumny* is — given that that’s  *calumniatory*. :)

Comment: @tchrist I could envisage speaking of 'a calumnious statement' (or 'remark' ), but I'm still not confident about 'a calumnious attempt'. It isn't the attempt that is 'calumnious', I would maintain. It is the substance of the attempt e.g 'an attempt at a calumnious story'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, and it is grammatical and understandable. It is probably not idiomatic. In English, two nouns are often used together this way, with the first "modifying" the second. Examples include *umbrella stand*, *baseball game*, *rape attempt*, *murder rap* (which has at least two meanings), *school book*, etc. When a combination is used with enough frequency, it is considered a compound noun.

Answer (score 2):

The standard usages I see are:

"attempt calumny" (calumny as a verb)
"attempt at calumny" (calumny as a noun)
"calumnious attempt" (calumny as an adjective, as noted by WS2 above)

To clarify, the last would be best used in phrases like "A calumnious attempt to secure the fortune" and not as an object itself. If you just mean "What he did was X.", I would use "What he did was an attempt at calumny" or "attempted calumny".

Comment: Do you call a *suicide attempt* a *suicidal attempt*? A *burglary attempt* a *larcenous attempt* or a *burglarious attempt*? An *escape attempt* an *escapist attempt* or an *evasive attempt*? The usage should be *calumny attempt*, and not *calumnious attempt*.

Comment: @Peter-Shor Yes, I've seen "suicidal attempt". However, the easiest way to set your mind at ease on this is google "a calumny attempt" (1 result in an informal message) vs. "a calumnious attempt", which includes several results in published articles. Not a lot, because the word is archaic and arcane, but definitely examples of that usage. (You have to include the "a" or you get a lot of results like "you did, by calumny, attempt" and the like.)

Comment: looking through the Google hits, most of the hits for *calumnious attempt* seem to be attempts that use calumny to try to do something, and not merely attempts at calumny. For example, *a calumnious attempt ,,,  to injure this new undertaking* and *a calumnious attempt to prevent his beatification*.

Comment: Which is why I edited my answer to make that clear, when I responded to your comment.